# Aggregation and grouping with dates and integers

Tags: views

I am using [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) along with [Highcharts](https://www.drupal.org/project/Highcharts) Module.

Here is my objective:

I have some integers that are contained in nodes 3 different integer fields to be exact.
These integers occur over a duration of time and are entered on various days.

What I am trying to do is sum all the integers that happen on the same day.

Example:

```
Day 1 - 5/24/12

node #1
integer field: 10

node #2
integer field: 10

node #3
integer field: 10

node #4
integer field: 10

node #5
integer field: 10

Day 2 - 5/30/12

node #1
integer field: 20

node #2
integer field: 20

node #3
integer field: 20

node #4
integer field: 20

node #5
integer field: 20
```

Desired output of data for highcharts would be:

```
Day 1 - 5/24/12
integer field: 50

Day 2 - 5/30/12
integer field: 100
```

I have tried to use grouping and aggregation but I could not get a desired display.
I could get all nodes to display but could reduced them down to the desired result.

Please let me know if I can clarify in any way or if this is even possible

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accomplish by setting my aggregation differently. I set it to sum and with value checked it began to work as documented. thanks. Let  me know if anyone is having trouble with aggregation its kinda tricky getting to function properly thanks!